# facebook-actionscript-api notworking anymore?

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, air

I developed a windows desktop software with adobe flash and air runtime. It runs on our local computer as console. I used the facebook-actionscript-api so to let user post image on their own facebook wall. It used to be working well.

until not long time ago, I found that the function not working anymore,
when I call the api, it opens an popup and shows an error code as below:

```
{
   "error": {
     "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 191
   }
}
```

It seems that facebook has changed something such as calling URL.
however ehen the latest adi "GraphAPI_Desktop_1_8_1.swc" don't seem to be working.

Are there any solutions?

I am also looking for the way to do javascript call in Adobe Air desktop so that I may call the native facebook js api. I don't found it so far. (probably coz my coding skill is not good enough)

Regards,
Wesley

Comment: Have you fixed that? I just faced the same issue, so any ideas would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

A.
 I have faced the same problem and was able to overcome it. The error 191 means that you use wrong callback URI while attempting to login. The problem comes from inside the facebook-actionscript-api library. If you download the source code of that library you'll find that it uses some predefined callback URIs (see LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL, LOGIN_SUCCESS_SECUREURL, LOGIN_FAIL_URL, LOGIN_FAIL_SECUREURL in api/com/facebook/graph/core/FacebookURLDefaults.as). I think these are old deprecated URLs that were used long ago :). At present you have to set up the correct callback URI for every Facebook application and pass that URI as a login request parameter and as you can see the library passes incorrect URL for you in that case. So my first step was to change these URIs inside the library (replace them with correct URLs). In my case I simply hardcoded them. I understand that this is not a best idea and it would be much better to add a possibility to set that URLs programmatically but to be frank I simply had no time for that.

After that you will find that login dialog loads fine but the access token can't be fetched from the callback URL parameters. The reason here is in fact that Facebook changed the Callback URL parameters format. Older version was

```
http://your_callback.com?access_token=bla-bla-bla
```

and new version adds # after ? and looks like:

```
http://your_callback.com?#access_token=bla-bla-bla.
```

There is a 'getURLVariables()' function (see desktopAPI/com/facebook/graph/windows/AbstractWindow.as) that is used to fetch parameters from URL. So I simply added one more 'if' condition (as a first one!) inside that function:

```
if (html.location.indexOf('?#') != -1) {
  params = html.location.slice(html.location.indexOf('?#')+2);
} else if ... (old code goes after my condition here)
```

These changes were enough to make the login flow work for me. I do not know if that will fix all your problems (like posting some content on the wall), but that may be a first step to make it work.

Note: I'm not an ActionScript developer at all and probably my approach was wrong so I'll appreсiate any comments on that solution.

B.
 As for your second idea about use of native JavaScript Facebook library. I assume the idea comes from that article (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html). The thing is you will have to use ExternalInterface to make 'bridging' between JavaScript and ActionScript. In my case (desktop AIR application) it is not possible because ExternalInterface is not supported in that case. You can check that like:

```
if (ExternalInterface.availabe) {...}
```

Hope that may help somebody...